# How to write BRST-BV for dg-Lie?

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, lie-algebra-cohomology

The usual BRST-BV implements a Lie algebra and its module in terms of ghosts, etc.
Where is there written a corresponding formula incorporating the differential of 
a dg Lie algebra and module?

Comment: http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/derived+critical+locus

Comment: I don't see this addresses my question, although the answer might be implicit. I want to be in the dg world *before* adding ghosts, e.g. starting with a dg Lie algebroid and a dg algebra of `fields'